# codelite build wxwidgets program no "-lwxmsw32ud_qa" error

Tags: wxwidgets, msys2, codelite

OS : windows 11, CPU : AMD, wxWidgets 3.2.4 Release,
the given link (msys2-x86_64-20231026.exe) of msys2 site, default package is ucrt64 version,
gcc info : gcc.exe (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.2.0.

I followed the guide on the official site,

mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=debug,

codelite version 17.0.0, and the compiler, enviroment variable, workspace settings all done well.

the problem is next, when I try to build the sample wxwidget program generated by codelite, the build omitted error that: "... ld.exe: cannot find -lwxmsw32ud_qa: No such file or directory".

```
C:/etc/msys64/ucrt64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j12 -e -f  Makefile
"----------Building project:[ wx - Debug ]----------"
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/dev/codelite/gui/wx'
C:/etc/msys64/ucrt64/bin/g++.exe -o ..\build-Debug\bin\wx.exe @../build-Debug/wx/ObjectsList.txt -L.   -mwindows -LC:/Downloads/wxwidgets323/lib/gcc_dll -pipe -lwxmsw32ud_xrc -lwxmsw32ud_webview -lwxmsw32ud_html -lwxmsw32ud_qa -lwxmsw32ud_adv -lwxmsw32ud_core -lwxbase32ud_xml -lwxbase32ud_net -lwxbase32ud
C:/etc/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxmsw32ud_qa: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [wx.mk:84: ..\build-Debug\bin\wx.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:5: All] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/dev/codelite/gui/wx'
=== build completed successfully (0 errors, 0 warnings) ===
```

what's "-lwxmsw32ud_qa"?
if the failure is the ucrt64 version of make or gcc problem? or it's from codelite?

I have strugled 3 days, still can't fixing it, need help!

thanks for any reply!

Comment: Did you build wxWidgets?  Did you build the debug build?  wxmsw32ud_qa is one of the Unicode debug libraries in wxWidgets.

Comment: Did you install wxWidgets in MSYS2?

Comment: I do build the library with debug on, but not do any install progress, just keep the entire wxwidgets diretory, and compiled the auto generated sample gui program. And how to do the installation?

Comment: @DanialTimmer, how did you create the project in CodeLite? The library you refer to is MSVC only...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself by do a new compilation, I was know nothing about make.
Thank you HolyBlackCat, you've give me the hint, install, I didn't found the official site mention about it.

I keep research, and found and followed an artical use cmake, did a fresh new compile, after that run 'mingw32-make install', in codelite set its environment viarable to 'WXCFG=gcc_x64_dll\mswud', build and run, it popup up twice says missing 'wxbase32ud_gcc_custom.dll' and 'wxmswd32ud_core_gcc_custom.dll', then keep researching and found the answer, I add the path of 'wxwidgets\lib\gcc_dll' to windows system virable, run the sample program again, the gui apeared, success!